# Find and Replace in Excel 2010 without losing cell formatting - unable to run on a cell that has 255 characters

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-2010

I am using this macro in Excel 2010 to find and replace words without losing cell formatting (e.g. some words are in bold, some are in italics so this macro just makes sure the cell keeps the same formatting when a word is replaced):

```
' Replacement of characters in the range(s) with storing of original Font
' Arguments:
'   Rng         - range for replacement
'   FindText    - string being searched for
'   ReplaceText - replacement string
'   MatchCase   - [False]/True, True to make the search case sensitive
Sub CharactersReplace(Rng As Range, FindText As String, ReplaceText As String, Optional MatchCase As Boolean)
  Dim i&, j&, jj&, k&, v$, m&, x As Range
  j = Len(FindText)
  jj = Len(ReplaceText)
  If Not MatchCase Then m = 1
  For Each x In Rng.Cells
    If VarType(x) = vbString Then
      k = 0
      i = 1
      With x
        v = .Value
        While i <= Len(v) - j + 1
          If StrComp(Mid$(v, i, j), FindText, m) = 0 Then
            .Characters(i + k, j).Insert ReplaceText
            k = k + jj - j
            i = i + j
          Else
            i = i + 1
          End If
        Wend
      End With
    End If
  Next
End Sub
' Testing subroutine
Sub Test_CharactersReplace()
  CharactersReplace Range("A743:F764"), "Replace This", "With This", True
End Sub
```

When I run the macro, there is an issue where the code doesn't work when a cell has more than 255 characters.

I've been looking this up online but have got no real solutions for this! Does any know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT::

It's not a simple solution, but basically what you need to do is this:

- get an array filled with values for the FontStyle of each character in the cell
- use Replace to replace each instance of your "old string" with your "new string"
- move the values in the array to reflect the change in string length
- write back both the string and the Fontstyle array to your cell

I managed to create something which works, it's a bit of a long one but I don't know of any other way of doing it.

Also, note that this only takes/replaces the Font Style (Bold, Italic etc) - it won't replicate any changes to color, size, font etc. These could easily be incorporated though, by adding more arrays and setting/amending their values inside the existing loops.

```
Public Sub RunTextChange()

Dim x as Range

For each x in Range("A743:F764")
    Call TextChange(x, "Replace This", "With This")
Next x

End Sub



Public Sub textchange(TargetCell As Range, FindTxt As String, ReplaceTxt As String)

''''Variables for text and length
Dim text1 As Variant: Dim text_length As Long
text1 = TargetCell.Value: text_length = Len(text1)

'variables for lengths of find/replace strings and difference
Dim strdiff As Long: Dim ftlen As Long: Dim rtlen As Long
ftlen = Len(FindTxt): rtlen = Len(ReplaceTxt): strdiff = rtlen - ftlen

'font arrays and loop integers
Dim fonts1 As Variant: Dim x As Long: Dim z As Long
Dim fonts2 As Variant
'set font array to length of string
ReDim fonts1(1 To text_length) As Variant
'make font array to correspond to the fontstyle of each character in the cell
For x = 1 To text_length
    fonts1(x) = TargetCell.Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle
Next x

'detect first instance of find text- if not present, exit sub
z = InStr(text1, FindTxt)
If z = 0 Then Exit Sub

'continue loop as long as there are more instances of find string
Do While z > 0
'replace each instance of find string in turn (rather than all at once)
text1 = Left(text1, z - 1) & Replace(text1, FindTxt, ReplaceTxt, z, 1)

    'if no difference between find and replace string lengths, there is no need to amend the fonts array
    If Not strdiff = 0 Then
        'otherwise, expand fonts array and push values forward (or back, if the replace string is shorter)
        fonts2 = fonts1
        ReDim Preserve fonts1(1 To text_length + strdiff) As Variant
        For x = z + ftlen To text_length
            fonts1(x + strdiff) = fonts2(x)
        Next x
        'set all the letters in the replacement string to the same font as the first letter in the find string
        For x = z To z + rtlen - 1
            fonts1(x) = fonts2(z)
        Next x
    End If

    'change text_length to reflect new length of string
    text_length = Len(text1)
    'change z to search for next instance of find string - if none, will exit loop
    z = InStr(z + rtlen, text1, FindTxt)
Loop

'change cell Value to new string
TargetCell.Value = text1
'change all characters to new font styles
For x = 1 To text_length
    TargetCell.Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle = fonts1(x)
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Using the Replace function in VBA loses the text formatting in Excel which is why I haven't used it

Comment: @C.Ron do you mean words within the cell have different formatting, or do you just mean the cell format? I can't think of a reason why Replace would "lose" the cell format, since it's only working on the values - I'd assumed that this was what you meant by cell formatting

Comment: words within the cell have different formatting. Using the replace VBA function makes all text inside a cell have the same format which I am trying to avoid

Comment: @C.Ron I've completely changed my answer now - managed to create a working solution, and it does work for over 255 chars (I tested it on around 650). It's a bit of a long one though. Also, this function is just for a single cell - if you wanted to do this on a range, you'd have to set up a loop and just call this on every cell

Comment: thanks a lot! But how would I go about setting up a loop to call on a range of cells?

Comment: @C.Ron you've already done that in your original code - you just need to have a seperate macro which loops over For each x in Rng.Cells, like your original macro does - except the only thing you need to put in the loop is-
    Call textchange(x, "Find Text", "Replace Text")

Comment: I've tried to create a separate macro but I can't get it to run. Can you give me an example of how to set up the loop please. Thanks

Comment: @C.Ron - I've amended my answer to include the seperate macro - it's at the top of the code, above the main macro

Comment: The code currently incorporates the Font Style Bold & Italics. How would I incorporate underline??

Comment: @C.Ron the structure I've given you will work, but underline isn't defined in the FontStyle property for the characters- it has a separate property. You just need a second array (e.g. underlines1) and copy the method I've used for getting the font styles. For example, under the line -- fonts1(x) = TargetCell.Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1).Font.FontStyle -- you'll want to insert the line -- underlines1(x) = TargetCell.Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1).Font.Underline -- you can similarly copy the existing structure to add the underlines back in.

Comment: Using the existing structure I've tried inserting the underline array but can't seem to make it work. Can you amend your existing answer with the underline array included please? thanks.